# Calculate remaining time in handler

Tags: java, android, timer, handler

I've got function which waits "syncingIntervalsInt" amount of time and then does the code. How can I create countdown? For example when syncingIntervalsInt is set to 10 seconds, I want to set one TextView to this countdown 10,9,8 etc.

Here is my function:

```
public void refreshRecycler()
{
    countingTillSync = syncingIntervalsInt;

    timerHandler = new Handler();

    timerRunnable = new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {

           //some code here
           countingTillSync--;


        }

        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, syncingIntervalsInt*1000); //run every second
    }


    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, syncingIntervalsInt*1000); //Start timer after 1 sec

}
```

This code above only decrements after syncingIntervalsInt*1000 amount of time which is not what I expect.

Comment: Could you check my answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this .

**1.Add `CountDownTimerUtils`**

```
public class CountDownTimerUtils extends CountDownTimer {

private TextView mTextView;

/**
 * @param textView          The TextView
 * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
 *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
 *                          is called.
 * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receiver
 *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
 */
public CountDownTimerUtils(TextView textView, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    this.mTextView = textView;
}
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    mTextView.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000 + "sec");
    mTextView.setClickable(false);
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    mTextView.setText("retry");
    mTextView.setClickable(true);
    mTextView.setFocusable(true);
}
}
```

**2.Set in your code like this .**

```
// 1 param yourTextView was TextView you want to set 
// 2 param  10 * 1000 was the number of millis in the future from the call
// 3 param 1000 was the interval along the way to receiver
CountDownTimerUtils mTimerUtils = new CountDownTimerUtils(yourTextView, 10 * 1000, 1000);
mTimerUtils.start();
```